# Библиотека "re"

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, library, re

С помощью импорта библиотеки "*re*" нужно проверить серийный номер на подлинность.
При этом буквенная часть должна состоять только из русско-английских букв.
Пример: A, B, C, E, H, K, M, O, P, T, X, Y

---

```
import re
a = input()  #A000AA
f = re.fullmatch( r'\w{1}*([ABCEHKMOPTXY])\d{3}\w{2}*([ABCEHKMOPTXY])', a)
print('Rigth' if f else 'Wrong')
```

---

Если основную чать оставить без **[ABCEHKMOPTXY]**, то все заработает, правда вводить можно любые буквы
`re.fullmatch( r'\w{1}\d{3}\w{2}', a)`
Помогите усовершенствовать
Пример:
A000BC T599OX Y200CE E666MN => Right
S000VC W599JX U200SD Q666ZA => Wrong

Comment: Пример приведите, пожалуйста

Comment: `\w` — буква, цифра или знак нижнего подчёркивания.

Comment: Привел пример, смотри выше

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vAy8pV/1/codegen?language=python - автоматически созданный код, https://regex101.com/r/vAy8pV/1 - пример захвата

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\w` используется для поиска любых букв, цифр и знака нижнего подчёркивания. Тут `\w` не нужен, так как разрешены только определённые буквы.

`\w{1}` — это то же самое, что `\w`, а `\w{1}*` — навалидный шаблон, нельзя в Python `re` квантифицировать квантификаторы ("сверхжадные" квантификаторы, такие как `++`, `?+`, `*+`, не поддерживаются).

Используйте

```
import re
a = 'A000AA'

pattern = r'[ABCEHKMOPTXY]\d{3}[ABCEHKMOPTXY]{2}'
print( bool(re.fullmatch( pattern, a)) )
# => True
```

См. [пример работы программы](https://ideone.com/L01jwx)

Если такие шаблоны часто повторяются, можно объявить эти шаблоны как переменные, а потом собрать регулярное выражение:

```
b = '[ABCEHKMOPTXY]'             # Определим шаблон для разрешённых букв
pattern = rf'{b}\d{{3}}{b}{{2}}' # Задаём регулярное выражение
```

См. [пример работы программы #2](https://ideone.com/my9VKK)

Comment: Спасибо большое, что быстро откликнулись и верно ответили,. Не могли бы вы поделится о том, что знаете о Регулярных-выражениях, это было бы  замечательно)

Comment: @NappySays Вы хотите, чтобы я написал книгу :) ?

Comment: А вы можете ? :)

Comment: @NappySays Могу, не нет конкретной идеи.

Comment: Как насчет поста? Это будет неоценимый вклад новичкам

Comment: @NappySays Если напишете о чём конкретно, может, напишу. Проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за мой ответ.

Comment: Я тут поискал про регулярные-выражения и наткнулся на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/#Gruppiruyuschie_skobki__i_matchobekty_v_pitone). Здесь как бы все понятно, но не написано как все это вот использовать. То есть, даже ваш ответ был более понятным. А именно хотелось бы перевести дословно что означают \w \W... ;  +  *...  и т.д. Ну и про findall, finditer, sub.  
Спасибо